# Power Menus plugin destroys menu after adding new item

Tags: plugins, menus

I use Wp 4.3 with Avada Theme 3.6.8.1. Avada support gives me a hint to solve a problem:
I have a big problem with my menu items in Power Menu plugin.
A lot are disappeared when updating (add) a menu item.
Also the Manage Location tab settings are not selected after an update.
When I do select them again, the complete menu is gone from the site.

From Avada support I get this solution:

---

To make this work I edited the priority numbers on the action calls that the plugin makes.
In particular the power-menus/power-menus.php:

```
add_action('wp_update_nav_menu_item', 'power_menus_custom_nav_update', 30, 5);
add_action('admin_init', 'power_menus_secure_page_meta_box');
add_action('init', 'power_menus_output_buffer', 0);
//add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'power_menus_admin_enqueue_scripts');
```

/* Filters */

```
add_filter('wp_edit_nav_menu_walker', 'power_menus_nav_walker', 30, 5);
add_filter('wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'power_menus_custom_nav_item');
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'power_menus_main_navigation_links', 30, 5);
```

Notice the numbers are 30, 5. This is higher than previously set, which means the plugin takes priority over the theme for menu item options.

WordPress has a limitation on the number of options added to the menus. So it cannot have both from the theme and from the plugin.

---

This just works a few days. Now not more. I have tried several combinations without success.

Has someone an idea how to solve this. From the developers WP Idiots, I do not get a reply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by deleting the plugin. Do not get any reply from the developers.
Just installed WPFront User Role Editor Pro plugin.

Comment: Finally found a good solution. 
Add this in .htaccess: 
php_value max_input_vars 3000
works great